# Is it possible to pass Query object as parameter of MongoRepository method?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I create mongodb **Query** object in service layer, then I call repository method and pass Query to it. I don't want to use annotation @Query. So, repository method should look something like this:

```
List<Person> findByQuery(Query query, Pageable pageable);
```

or simply `find(...)`. But when I build the project, there are errors in tests. It says:

> No property 'query' found for type 'Person'

or

> No property 'find' found for type 'Person'! Did you mean
> ''id''?

Obviously, the name of method is incorrect. How should I name the method to make Spring generate code?

Answer (score 0):

As `Query` is a persistence technology-specific abstraction (in this case MongoDB), it is supposed to be used *within* the repository. The service layer shouldn't actually need to refer such a type. This means that query methods need to be composed of domain types and either bound to a derived or declared query.

If you want to create the `Query` instance yourself, the way to go is a custom repository method implementation. How to declare them is described in [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

Comment: I want to make a single `find` method because currently I have more than 10 methods in repository. All of them are doing certain filtering, I choose among them depending on which fields user has passed in http request. Seems like it's impossible to simply pass a `Query` to `MongoRepository`. I need to write a custom repo where I internally call `MongoTemplate` to do those filtering

Comment: If you want to dynamically create filter expressions, you might wanna check out the Querydsl support, alongside the support for deriving the predicates from HTTP request parameters. Let your repository extend `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl), the web support is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe).